# 2 instances of Xcode installed?

Tags: install, xcode, launchpad

I originally installed Xcode via Apple's developer website (not through the App Store). Later on, I installed Xcode via the App Store.

Now in Launchpad, I have two icons for each of these apps: Xcode, Instruments, Dashcode, and Quartz Composer. None of the icons have an "X" button to remove them from Launchpad.

Questions:

1. Does this mean that I have 2 versions of Xcode installed?
2. If not, how can I verify that I only have one version installed?
3. How can I know which file each Launchpad icon is referencing?
4. If it's purely a cosmetic thing, how would I get rid of the second set of icons? (And does it matter which set I get rid of?)

Update:

I see that the `/Developer` folder contains an `Applications` folder, but it also contains `SDKs`, `Documentation`, `Platforms`, etc.

My `/Applications` folder contains the folder `Developer`. Inside of `/Applications/Developer`, there are 4 aliases which link to the `/Developer` folder. For example, the Xcode alias (`/Applications/Developer/Xcode`) links to `/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app`.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Launchpad. Try typing "Xcode" into Spotlight instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the latest Xcode (4.3.2 at time of writing) it should be in /Applications/Xcode. You may have an older Xcode in /Developer. /Developer is now no longer used by Xcode. You should remove it using the provided script if you don't need the old version any more. Execute

```
sudo /Xcode4/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

and authenticate. When that script completes you can remove the /Developer folder entirely but you should allow Xcode's script to take care of its somewhat "fragile" installation first.

New Xcode lives in /Applications and is much more like a conventional Mac OS X app these days. Lots more information about putting it in the dock, finding other developer apps, command line tools etc. in this [other answer of mine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/44859/3117).

Answer (score 1):

2 Xcode versions can co-exist on a mac, we use it in our company for checking backward compatibility. Till date, we have never faced any issues because of this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you installed two Xcode versions in parallel?

Comment: just install it in two different folder locations . My old version is in /Developer and latest Xcode in /Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The old version of Xcode used to reside in /Developer whereas the current version has been moved to the standard /Applications.  Consider checking both locations for the program.  It is safe to delete the /Developer folder if you have the current version installed.

Comment: Delete the entire `/Developer` folder? It seems like that would get rid of everything. I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Sounds like your system has been modified.  XCode 4.3.2 definitely installs to `/Applications/XCode.app` and ignores any existing `/Developer/` folder.

Just to be clear, a path beginning with '/' is in the root of the hard drive.

Comment: Yes, I'm following the same convention of `/` at the beginning refers to root. Perhaps it's because I originally installed it through Apple's website rather than the App Store. I guess the solution I would prefer at this point is to uninstall everything and reinstall via the App Store.

Comment: Don't delete the /Developer folder - run the script and let it uninstall itself first. Most times on a Mac I agree you can just trash the folder but not this time.